# PIG Latin: Output Path based on Field Value

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a Logfile which contains logs from multiple domains. Now I want to do some analytics on them and STORE the output in a directory named like the domain. I have the domain as a field value in my logs:

```
STORE outputlogs INTO 'testpath/DOMAIN/logs USING....
```

Is this possible? Or can I only store the outputs in a hardcoded filepath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of the domain is a field in `outputlogs` then you can use [`MultiStorage`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html) from piggybank.  Something like:

```
STORE outputlogs INTO 'testpath/DOMAIN/logs' 
                 USING MultiStorage('testpath/DOMAIN/logs','0') ;
```

Where `0` is the positional field of the domain.